# Entity Framework code first duplicating the foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm getting duplicated foreign key in one of my tables. I'm using EF code first and mapping the tables with Fluent API. I have no idea why this is happening.

Class that represents the table:

```
public class ColunaSugestUsuario 
{
    [Key]
    public int CODCOLSUGEST { get; set; }
    public ColunaSugest COLSUGEST { get; set; }
    public Usuarios USUARIO { get; set; }
    public Sugestoes SUGESTOES { get; set; }
    public int CODINDEX { get; set; }
}
```

Note: Every custom class in this code contains an `ICollection` of `ColunaSugestUsuario` named `COLUNASUGESTUSUARIO`.

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ColunaSugestUsuario>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.COLSUGEST)
    .WithMany(s => s.COLUNASUGESTUSUARIO)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("CODSUGEST"));
modelBuilder.Entity<ColunaSugestUsuario>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.USUARIO)
    .WithMany(s => s.COLUNASUGESTUSUARIO)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("CODCOLUNA"));
modelBuilder.Entity<ColunaSugestUsuario>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.SUGESTOES)
    .WithMany(s => s.COLUNASUGESTUSUARIO)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("CODUSUARIO"));
```

Result:

[image]

This *ColunaSugest_CODCOLUNA* should not be there. Right?

**Edit:**

I've already tried a fully defined relationship at both ends as well (the foreign key as a class attribute), but nothing happened

Comment: The `public ColunaSugest COLSUGEST { get; set; }` need to declare as virtual to connect the other class. I suppose `ColunaSugest` represent a table.

Comment: @Llazar I saw some questions at Stack Overflow using `virtual` but the other tables in my project are working properly and there is nothing about it at EF website (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). Besides, I changed to virtual and still the same

Comment: Q: Could you please post the code for `ColunaSugest`? PS: what does "ColunaSugest" mean in English?  Just curious...

Comment: @paulsm4 "coluna" = column, "Sugest" is an abbreviation for "Sugestão" which simply means suggestion. I've found the issue thanks to you. I was using two `ICollection<ColunaSugestUsuario>` in the `ColunaSugest` class. Idk how I couldn't see it before,Ii guess Im just too tired. But thanks.